# Intermittent net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a React website. After I make a change and then refresh the browser (Chrome) I often get the console error:

`net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)`

Looking at the network tab in developer tools I see:

`main.js status: failed, size: 198KB, time: 248ms.`

However, this error is intermittent. If I refresh the page several times it finally decides to load.

What are some reasons that I would be experiencing an intermittent issue like this?

**Update**

I have narrowed it down to the wired connection at my work place. It works fine on wireless and other places I take the laptop. Other devices on the wired network have the same issue. It loads main.js partway and then fails.

This is not browser specific as the problem occurs both on Chrome and Edge.

However, every other site I connect with on the wired network seems to work fine, so it is just my React site that is having issues on the wired network.

What else could be the problem?

Comment: Seemingly random question, but are you using any a `fetch` statement anywhere?  I ran into similar, and swapped it with an `axios.get()` statement and it seemed to go away.

Comment: @cfnerd I do have a fetch. I removed that and still have the same issue.